# Limit javascript functionality to One Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This might be simple question for some, but I am missing something, and would love to get some help:

I have the desired correct functionality in the SELECT field:

1. Either select an option, or type a new one on the select box
2. selects it as the SELECTED value
3. resulting in value = SELECTED

**The issue:** 
The javascript fills *all* other INPUT fields the the form with the selected value

Is there any way to limit the functionality of the javascript to only that field or better yet,  to certain fields within the form, so I can re-use on other fields?

Many thanks in advanced!

Code follows:

```
<html>
<!-- adapted from original javascript code source:        http://ughzoid.wordpress.com/2013/01/19/jquery-html-select-element-with-editable-input-field/  -->

<head>
<STYLE type="text/css">
select{position:absolute; width:160px;height:23px; left:10; top:30; border:0;}
input{ position:absolute; width:140px;height:17px; left:10; top:30;}
p{position: relative; margin-top:50px;}

</STYLE>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Special Select Handling...</title>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
    $('select').change(function(){ 
        modify();
    })

    function modify(){
        $('input').val($('select').val());
        output();
    }

    function output(){
        $('p').text('value: ' + $('input').val());
    }

    $('input').on('click', function(){
        $(this).select()
    }).on('blur', function(){
        output();
    })

    modify();
    })

    // Plugin
    $.fn.iWouldLikeToAbsolutelyPositionThingsInsideOfFrickingTableCellsPlease = function() {
    // Original source: http://css-tricks.com/absolutely-position-element-within-a-table-cell/
        var $el;
        return this.each(function() {
            $el = $(this);
            var newDiv = $("<div />", {
                "class": "innerWrapper",
                "css"  : {
                    "height"  : $el.height(),
                    "width"   : "100%",
                    "position": "relative"
                }
            });
            $el.wrapInner(newDiv);    
        });
    };

    // DOM Ready
    $(function() {
        // Usage
        $("th, td").iWouldLikeToAbsolutelyPositionThingsInsideOfFrickingTableCellsPlease();
    });

</script>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Special Select Handling ... </h2>

<div id="cell0">
<table border="1">
 <tr> 
    <td width="170px">1/2 <br /></td>
    <td width="170px">1/3 <br /></td>
    <td width="170px">1/4 <br /></td>
    <td width="170px">1/5 <br /></td>
  </tr>

 <tr>
    <td>Standard Text Field:<br /> <br /></td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="strategy" id="strategy" value="text field 1" /><br /></td>
    <td>2/4 </td>
    <td>2/5 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>Special Field:<br /></td>
    <td  style="width:160px; height:30px">
        <div id="cell1">
        <select>
            <option selected="selected" value="100">100</option>
            <option value="200">200</option>
            <option value="300">300</option>
            <option value="400">400</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="" value="">    
        </div>
        <br />
    </td>
    <td><p>value:</p>       <script src="js/jquery.calculator.js"></script>    </td>
    <td>this is the correct functionality:  Either select an option, or type a new one on the select box and selects it as the SELECTED value  <br><Br>
    the issue is that this javascrip fills *all* other INPUT fields the the form  with the selected value </td>


   <tr>
    <td>Another Text Field:<br />asd </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" value="" /><br /></td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>

  </tr>
   <tr> 

    <td width="170px">5/2 <br /></td>
    <td width="170px">5/3 <br /></td>
    <td width="170px">5/4 <br /></td>
    <td width="170px">5/5 <br /></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('input')` selector affects all the `input` elements on the page. To restrict its scope, you may do many various things, but usually you assign an `id` to your input element:

```
<input type='text' id='myinput' ... >
```

and then reference this id in selectors:

```
$('input#myinput')
```

Study what [CSS Selectors](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnet.tutsplus.com%2Ftutorials%2Fhtml-css-techniques%2Fthe-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize%2F&ei=a5C3UtuzLMqWyAPy8IDoDg&usg=AFQjCNHsozintlEgoByzbdMWIfgBsiixVA&sig2=colCIxPHBthB9nDWsZNz5g&bvm=bv.58187178,d.bGQ) are.

Comment: `$("input#myinput")` is redundant and prevents jQuery from optimising to a `getElementById` call.

Comment: I believe that the OP needs to get the very basic idea first and care about performance later.

Comment: Then you believe wrong. Performance is essential to learn right from the start, otherwise it will be extremely difficult to learn.